# Denormalizing a DataFrame of company names [Part 2]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the continuation of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922806/denormalizing-a-dataframe-of-company-names) on denormalizing a DataFrame of company names.

The revised table I'm now working with is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Nitron', 'Pulset', 'Rotaxi'], 
                   'postal_code' : [1410, 1020, 1310], 
                   'previous_name1' : ['Rotory', np.NaN, 'Datec'],
                   'previous_name2' : [ np.NaN, 'Cmotor', np.NaN],
                   'previous_name3' : ['Datec', np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'country' : ['BEL', 'ENG', 'JPN'], 
                   'city' : ['Brussels', np.NaN, np.NaN]
                  })

print(df)

| name   | postal_code | previous_name1 | previous_name2 | previous_name3 | country | city     |
|--------|-------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|---------|----------|
| Nitron | 1410        | Rotory         | NaN            | Datec          | BEL     | Brussels |
| Pulset | 1020        | NaN            | Cmotor         | NaN            | ENG     | NaN      |
| Rotaxi | 1310        | Cyclip         | NaN            | NaN            | JPN     | NaN      |
```

Comparing to my previous post, the above DataFrame has now two additional columns, namely the `country` and `city` Series.

My objective remains the same: add a new row for all instances where the previous company names is non-missing **with the `country` and `city` columns** and delete the previous names Series afterwards. Visually, the "denormalized" version should look like this:

```
| name   | postal_code | country | city     |
|--------|-------------|---------|----------|
| Nitron | 1410        | BEL     | Brussels |
| Rotory | 1410        | BEL     | Brussels |
| Datec  | 1410        | BEL     | Brussels |
| Pulset | 1020        | ENG     | NaN      |
| Cmotor | 1020        | ENG     | NaN      |
| Rotaxi | 1310        | JPN     | NaN      |
| Cyclip | 1310        | JPN     | NaN      |
```

After spending some time understanding the [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922806/denormalizing-a-dataframe-of-company-names) provided by **jezrael** for my previous question, I tried to modify/adjust the solution for this new problem without success. Since I'm fairly new to the Python/Pandas ecosystem, any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple columns in `set_index` and change `level=1` to `level=3` for remove forth level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['postal_code','country','city'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='name')
         )
print (df1)
   postal_code country      city    name
0         1410     BEL  Brussels  Nitron
1         1410     BEL  Brussels  Rotory
2         1410     BEL  Brussels   Datec
3         1020     ENG       NaN  Pulset
4         1020     ENG       NaN  Cmotor
5         1310     JPN       NaN  Rotaxi
6         1310     JPN       NaN   Datec
```

And for second solution add multiple columns to `melt`:

```
df1 = (df.melt(['postal_code','country','city'], value_name='name')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .dropna(subset=['name'])
         .reset_index( drop=True)
)
print (df1)
   postal_code country      city    name
0         1410     BEL  Brussels  Nitron
1         1020     ENG       NaN  Pulset
2         1310     JPN       NaN  Rotaxi
3         1410     BEL  Brussels  Rotory
4         1310     JPN       NaN   Datec
5         1020     ENG       NaN  Cmotor
6         1410     BEL  Brussels   Datec
```