# How to add flag to each entry in existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Problem

Given this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

```py
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

what is the simplest route to this:

```py
        0       1       2
0  (1, 0)  (2, 0)  (3, 0)
1  (4, 0)  (5, 0)  (6, 0)
2  (7, 0)  (8, 0)  (9, 0)
```

---

## Considered Questions and Approaches

Is there a way to convert the existing dataframe to a dataframe of tuples?

I haven't found a way to do so, nor thought of a better alternative, so my current approach is to create a new `df`, replacing each entry with a tuple `(entry, flag)`.

In order to do that I would like to [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) or [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) the original `df` to a `df` with empty tuples `(0, 0)`, to avoid manually iterating over and reformating each entry into the new `df`.

Note, I would like to add the flag to each entry, not each row, making this question different from [Adding binary flag to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959584/adding-binary-flag-to-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: (x, 0))`

Comment: Do you need the tuples? You could get the same information with a MutliIndex on the columns, which then won't lead to major performance issues for subsequent operations. Even something as trivial as counting the non-zero flags is slow/problematic once you have tuples.

Comment: What do you want to do with the flag? Better use a second dataframe of booleans as mask.

Comment: @mozway It needs to be a single file.

Comment: @ALollz, that's an interesting idea. If you could make an answer with an example of how to use the data stored in the MultiIndex column I'll consider it. Edit: Oh, but then in order to access the data, I'd need to know the flag value. Or I guess I could use `df.columns[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> Actually, it seems we need to make it a list since tuples are immutable

Simple use `applymap` (cell by cell):

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: [x, 0])
        0       1       2
0  [1, 0]  [2, 0]  [3, 0]
1  [4, 0]  [5, 0]  [6, 0]
2  [7, 0]  [8, 0]  [9, 0]
```

Or `apply` with a comprehension:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: [[i, 0] for i in x])
        0       1       2
0  [1, 0]  [2, 0]  [3, 0]
1  [4, 0]  [5, 0]  [6, 0]
2  [7, 0]  [8, 0]  [9, 0]
```

Comment: Actually, it seems we need to make it a `list` since `tuples` are immutable.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment.