# How to read in dataframe of lists from csv

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**

Given:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [x, 0])
```

```py
        0       1       2
0  [1, 0]  [2, 0]  [3, 0]
1  [4, 0]  [5, 0]  [6, 0]
2  [7, 0]  [8, 0]  [9, 0]
```

```py
df.to_csv("list_entries.csv")
```

How do you read the data back in, preserving the original data types?

---

**What I've Tried**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661877/4682839) mentions use of `converters`, but I can't figure out how
to apply it to all columns.

I've tried instead to use `applymap()`:

```py
import ast
df.applymap(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

but get this error:

```
NameError: name 'ast' is not defined
```

(Follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744058/how-to-add-flag-to-each-entry-in-existing-pandas-dataframe).)

Edit:
From my debugger:

```py
(Pdb) df.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
*** NameError: name 'ast' is not defined
(Pdb) ast
<module 'ast' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py'>
```

Edit:
Oddly it works fine outside the debugger.

Comment: Use `import ast`

Comment: With nested data, I recommend using `to_pickle` and `read_pickle`. Or you can use `to_json` and `read_json` if you insist on text data.

Comment: no need to import `ast`
`df['0'] = df['0'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))`

Comment: @DanialShabbir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Comment: @DanialShabbir That noted, yea I could get away with less dependencies.